# fetch the data once the user hover the mouse on a map

Tags: python, geopandas

I use the geopandas to visualize the data in the map after I merge the goepandas data frame with the numeric data frame. I want to render this data once the user hover  over the country that this data belongs to it .right now I mange to render the coordinate as annotation where the mouse is over but I need the data

```
enter code genertate() : Map_Figure, Map_Graph = plt.subplots()
dataset = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = pd.DataFrame(dataset[['name', 'geometry', 'iso_a3']])
data2 = (records['Location'].value_counts()).reset_index()
data2.columns = ['name', 'Number']
data2['Number'] = data2['Number'].apply(int)
annot = Map_Graph.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
datum = world.set_index('name').join(data2.set_index('name'))

World = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(datum)
#print(Map_Graph)
basePlot = World.plot(ax=Map_Graph, column='Number', linewidth=0.1, edgecolor='black', cmap='nipy_spectral',
                      vmin=World['Number'].min(), vmax=World['Number'].max(), legend=True)
# worldPlot= World.plot(ax=Map_Graph, color= 'white', edgecolor='black', cmap='tab10', scheme='QUANTILES', figsize=(8, 4))

locations = data2.values
box = []
for word, count in locations[:10]:
    string = '%s | %s posts' % (word, human_format(count))
    if len(string) >= 27:
        string = string[:27] + " \n" + string[27:]
    else:
        string = string
    box.append(string)

s = '\n'.join(box)
mapText = '%s ' % (s)
Map_Graph.text(-340, -80, mapText, size='small', wrap=True,
               bbox={'boxstyle': 'round', 'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 0.8})

Map_Graph.set_axis_off()
Map_Figure.set_tight_layout(True)
Map_Figure.savefig("Report/data/Map.png")
mapCursor(Map_Graph)
Map_Figure.set_size_inches(6, 3.3)



return Map_Figure,basePlothere
```

and the fowling code to render the data where the mouse hover

```
enter code here

 self.mapFigure,ax= AM.generate_Map()
    #hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Country/region', '@country'), ('% obesity', '@per_cent_obesity')])
    self.mapGraphs = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.gPanel_map, -1, self.mapFigure)
    datacursor(ax, xytext=(15, -15), bbox=dict(fc='white'), arrowprops=None, hover=True,
               formatter='{x.d}: \n{y}'.format)
```

Comment: Does geopandas actually provide interactive plotting, or just a static plot with extra annotations (on hover) based on data attributes/values? Might be required to switch over to folium/leaflet to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Than you for your answer . I don't know I'm new on python .but the library that you mentioned is a java script library.. there is no such this library works in wxpython Gui ?